# Oracle function POWER gives approximate results

Tags: oracle

Recently I found out that ORACLE function POWER does not always give exact results.
This can be easily checked by this script or similar:

```
BEGIN
 FOR X IN 1 .. 100 LOOP
  IF SQRT(X) = POWER(X, 1 / 2) THEN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(X);
  END IF;
 END LOOP;
END;
```

The output results are just following: 1, 5, 7, 11, 16, 24, 35, 37, 46, 48, 53, 70, 72, 73.
I.e. we see the situation when only in 14 cases from 100 first natural numbers the square root of a number is equal to its exponentiation with an index of 1/2.

Comment: And what's the question? This is observation only.

Comment: Don't have access to sqlplus now. Try to replace `POWER(X, 1 / 2)` with `X**0.5`.

Comment: You are trying to compare real numbers. You need to truncate to your desired precision.

Answer (score 2):

I think this has to do with the limits to the NUMBER data type.  I believe NUMBER precision can only go to 38 max.  If you try with BINARY_DOUBLE, you'll find all values 1->100 will match:

```
DECLARE
  l_num binary_double := 0;
BEGIN
    LOOP
        l_num := l_num + 1;
        exit when l_num > 100;
        IF ( SQRT(l_num) = POWER(l_num, 0.5) ) THEN
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_num);
        ELSE
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_num || ': ' || SQRT(l_num) || ' <> ' || POWER(l_num, 0.5));
        END IF;
     END LOOP;
END;
```

Output (partial):

```
1.0E+000
2.0E+000
3.0E+000
...
9.8E+001
9.9E+001
1.0E+002
```

Another option is to round the results of both SQRT and POWER to, say, 35 or less (if you must use NUMBER datatype).

Answer (score 2):

The [Oracle documentation somewhat covers this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions002.htm):

> **Numeric Functions**
>
> Numeric functions accept numeric input and return numeric values. Most
>   numeric functions return NUMBER values that are accurate to 38 decimal
>   digits. The transcendental functions `COS`, `COSH`, `EXP`, `LN`,
>   `LOG`, `SIN`, `SINH`, `SQRT`, `TAN`, and `TANH` are accurate to 36
>   decimal digits. The transcendental functions `ACOS`, `ASIN`, `ATAN`,
>   and `ATAN2` are accurate to 30 decimal digits.

So `SQRT` is stated to be accurate to 36 decimal digits; but `POWER` isn't in the list so it is implied to be accurate to 38 decimal digits. If you look at the values returned by the two functions you can see the discrepancy way down in the least significant digits; e.g. for `X = 2`:

```
SQRT(2):       1.41421356237309504880168872420969807857
POWER(2, 1/2): 1.41421356237309504880168872420969807855
```

Curiously, though, it looks like `SQRT` is more accurate and it's `POWER` that is slightly less precise, as you stated. [Wolfram Alpha gives](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%282%29):

```
               1.4142135623730950488016887242096980785696718753769480...
```

(but notice that also states it's an approximation), which rounds to the same as `SQRT`; and if you reverse the process with `SQRT(2) * SQRT(2)` and `POWER((POWER(2, 1/2), 2)` you get:

```
(SQRT):        2
(POWER):       1.99999999999999999999999999999999999994
```

When `X` is a `binary_double` rather than a `number` you get the same value for both:

```
               1.4142135623730951
```

but you've lost precision; squaring that again gives:

```
               2.0000000000000004
```

Ultimately any decimal representation of a floating point number has a limit to its precision, and will be an approximation. Two functions giving slightly different approximations is perhaps a little confusing, but since they seem to have `SQRT` a closer approximation (despite what the documentation says) - as a special case - I'm not sure that's really something to complain about.